# Create List of 30 Minute Time Intervals between 2 dates

Tags: excel, vba, date, intervals

Post about WriteDates on this link [How to list all dates by every 2 hours between two given dates in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159167/how-to-list-all-dates-by-every-2-hours-between-two-given-dates-in-excel) works really well for hours, but as the notes suggest " If the value zero, it will default to 1 day interval". I tried setting value to 0.5 for 30 minutes. I want to accomplish something like: Start: 10/1/20 7:00 End: 10/4/2020 13:00 and increments of like 15 minutes or 30 minutes or 45 minutes. Result for 30 minute duration would look like:
10/1/20 7:00
10/1/20 7:30
10/1/20 8:00
10/1/20 8:30
10/1/20 9:00
10/1/20 9:30
10/1/20 10:00
10/1/20 10:30
...
10/2/20 12:30 (last 30 minute slot)
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need VBA at all for this? A simple formula will work.

Comment: If your `Start` is in cell `A1` and has this value: `10/1/2020 7:00:00 AM` then the following formula in cell `B1` gives you a 15-minute increment: `=A1+1/24/4`

Comment: Similarly, a 30-minute increment would be achieved like this: `=A1+1/24/2`

Comment: As said in the comments, Excel formula will work. VBA code will also work but what did you try and where do you have a problem or is the question just about modifying the code from the link provided for you. A third approach could be to use Power Query `List.DateTimes([Start],Duration.TotalHours([End] - [Start])*4+1 ,#duration(0,0,15,0))`

Answer (score 0):

### Generate Time Intervals

- Adjust the constants in the 1st, main procedure `generateTimeIntervals` to fit your needs and run it afterwards.
- The 2nd procedure `getTimeIntervals` is being called by the main procedure.
- Additionally you can play with the line `getTimeIntervals Data, StartTime, EndTime, MinutesInterval`. After these 4 arguments, there are 3 more that are omitted (adjusted to the setup in your post e.g. if you set `include2ndColumn` to `True`, you will get two columns: `From` and `To`. The remaining two arguments are pretty self explanatory.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub generateTimeIntervals()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const StartLocation As String = "B1"
    Const EndLocation As String = "B2"
    Const ResultLocation As String = "B3"
    Const MinutesInterval As Long = 30
    Const NumFormat As String = "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim StartTime As Date
    StartTime = ws.Range(StartLocation)
    Dim EndTime As Date
    EndTime = ws.Range(EndLocation)
    
    ' Generate time intervals to Result Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    getTimeIntervals Data, StartTime, EndTime, MinutesInterval
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then
        GoTo NoData
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Result Array to Result Range.
    With ws.Range(ResultLocation)
        ' Clear Result Range Column(s) starting from Result Location.
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - ws.Range(ResultLocation).Row + 1, _
                UBound(Data, 2)).Clear
        ' Apply formatting to Result Range.
        .Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).NumberFormat = NumFormat
        ' Write values from Result Array to Result Range.
        .Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
    End With
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Generated " & UBound(Data, 1) & " time intervals.", _
           vbInformation, "Success"

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
    
NoData:
    MsgBox "Unable to generate.", vbExclamation, "No Data"
    GoTo ProcExit

End Sub

Sub getTimeIntervals(ByRef Data As Variant, _
                     ByVal StartTime As Date, _
                     ByVal EndTime As Date, _
                     MinutesInterval As Long, _
                     Optional include2ndColumn As Boolean = False, _
                     Optional includeLast As Boolean = False, _
                     Optional excludeFirst As Boolean = False)
    
    Data = Empty
    If EndTime <= StartTime Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim Interval As Double
    Interval = MinutesInterval / 24 / 60
    
    Dim addLast As Long
    If includeLast Then
        addLast = 1
    End If
    
    Dim removeFirst As Long
    If excludeFirst Then
        removeFirst = 1
    End If
    
    Dim DataCount As Long
    DataCount = (EndTime - StartTime) / Interval + addLast - removeFirst
    If DataCount < 1 Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim CurrentTime As Date
    CurrentTime = StartTime + removeFirst * Interval
    Dim i As Long
    If include2ndColumn Then
        ReDim Data(1 To DataCount, 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            Data(i, 1) = CurrentTime
            CurrentTime = CurrentTime + Interval
        Next i
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To DataCount, 1 To 2)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            Data(i, 1) = CurrentTime
            CurrentTime = CurrentTime + Interval
            Data(i, 2) = CurrentTime
        Next i
    End If

ProcExit:

End Sub
```

Comment: tyvm this looks very promising. I will test it out and update with progress.

Comment: `GoSub` really?

Comment: @ExcelHero: I've edited my code. Since you have already complained, could you be so kind and take a look to see if there is anything else out of practice, old fashioned or whatever. I really would appreciate it. Thanks anyway.